# Delete Rows which values < 500 and Rounding Values > 500 VB.net?

Tags: excel, vb.net, criteria

I have a Column in excel which has numbers with Decimals, Which if they are less than 500 I want to delete and if they are bigger than 500, i want to round the number to become without decimals.

I use the below code which does not give any errors but does not do the job, Please Check this Code:

```
    Private Sub DeleteCells_T08()
        Dim xl As New Excel.Application
        Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
        Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim Rng As Excel.Range
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim currentcell As Excel.Range
        Dim lRow As Long
        xl.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Patches\Main_Master_VB.xlsm")
        ws = wb.Sheets("Result_T08")
        With ws
            lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
        End With
        Rng = ws.Range("B2", "B" & lRow)
        For i = Rng.Rows.count To 1 Step -1
            If Rng.Cells(i).Value < 500 Then
                Rng.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            Else
                For Each currentcell In Rng
                    currentcell.Value = xl.WorksheetFunction.Round(currentcell.Value, 0)
                Next currentcell
            End If
        Next i
        xl.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub
```

Your help is Highly Appreciated, Thanks

Moheb Labib

Comment: `but does not do the job` - clearly it does *something*? What is `Rng.Address`, what is `i` in the end?

Comment: @ GSerg, The i for counter and the numbers like 125.50 which is lesser than 500 is not deleted

Comment: @GSerg, Kindly be informed that this code is working perfect with VBA but the problem that I am transferring the application to VB.net, the VBA Accepts the Rng to be declared as variant which solves the problem, but I can not declare Variant in VB.net, I tried Object, VariantType, but it is not working, thanks

Comment: I Edited the Code Above to Be Like VBA Code Which is working

Comment: Please show also you VB.NET code

Comment: @ThomasG This is the vb.net code.

Comment: @Thomas G, This is my Vb.Net Code Above, The only difference is that the Range is defined as Variant not Range Not object

Answer (score 0):

I found the Answer

```
    Private Sub DeleteCells()
        Dim xl As New Excel.Application
        Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
        Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim Rng As Excel.Range
        Dim lRow As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        xl.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Patches\Main_Master_VB.xlsm")
        ws = wb.Sheets("Result_T08")
        With ws
            lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
        End With
        Rng = ws.Range("B2", "B" & lRow)
        For i = lRow To 1 Step -1
            Dim line As Excel.Range
            line = CType(Rng.Cells(i, 1), Excel.Range)
            If CDbl(line.Value) < 500 Then
                line.EntireRow.Delete()
            Else
                line.Value = xl.WorksheetFunction.Round(CDbl(line.Value), 0)
            End If
        Next
        xl.DisplayAlerts = True
        wb.Close(SaveChanges:=True)
        xl.Quit()
    End Sub
```